# How to make Scrapy crawl only 1 page (make it non recursive)?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using the latest version of scrapy (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html) and am trying to figure out how to make scrapy crawl only the URL(s) fed to it as part of start_url list. In most cases I want to crawl only 1 page, but in some cases there may be multiple pages that I will specify. I don't want it to crawl to other pages.

I've tried setting the depth level=1 but I'm not sure that in testing it accomplished what I was hoping to achieve.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

2015-12-22 - Code update:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from generic.items import GenericItem

class GenericspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "genericspider"

    def __init__(self, domain, start_url, entity_id):
        self.allowed_domains = [domain]
        self.start_urls = [start_url]
        self.entity_id = entity_id


    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css("a::attr('href')"):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("//body//a"):
            item = GenericItem()

            item['entity_id'] = self.entity_id
            # gets the actual email address
            item['emails'] = response.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]").re(r'mailto:\s*(.*?)"')


            yield item
```

Below, in the first response, you mention using a generic spider --- isn't that what I'm doing in the code? Also are you suggesting I remove the

```
callback=self.parse_dir_contents
```

from the parse function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you are using `CrawlSpider` which is a special kind of `Spider` to crawl multiple categories inside pages.

For only crawling the urls specified inside `start_urls` just override the `parse` method, as that is the default callback of the start requests.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I added a code sample to the post and a question for a little more clarification. Happy holidays, btw!

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code for the spider that will scrape the title from a blog (Note: the xpath might not be the same for every blog)

Filename: /spiders/my_spider.py

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "craig"
allowed_domains = ["www.blogtrepreneur.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.blogtrepreneur.com/the-best-juice-cleanse-for-weight-loss/"]


def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    dive = response.xpath('//div[@id="tve_editor"]')
    items = []
    item = DmozItem()
    item["title"] = response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()
    item["article"] = response.xpath('//div[@id="tve_editor"]//p//text()').extract()
    items.append(item)
    return items
```

The above code will only fetch the title and the article body of the given article.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, because I was using

```
import scrapy from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
```

Then I changed to

```
import scrapy from scrapy.spiders import Spider
```

And change the class to

```
class mySpider(Spider):
```